# Case statement SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, case

I trying to re-write this Microsoft Access IF statement as a CASE statement in SQL Server 2008:

```
 Status: IIf(
             IIf(B.[Online Class Completion Date] Is Null,
             Null,
             DateDiff("w",A.[Trust Start Date],B.[Online Class Completion Date])
             ) <=6,
         "Pass",
         IIf(
             IIf(B.[Online Class Completion Date] Is Null,
             Null,
             DateDiff("w",A.[Trust Start Date],B.[Online Class Completion Date])
             ) >6,
             "Fail",
         IIf(DateDiff("w",A.[Trust Start Date],MAX(B.[Month])) <=6,
         "NotApp",
         "Never"
         )
         )
         )
```

I've tried various different ways but I just cant seem to get the nesting right.  I get Pass and Fails but no NotApps or Nevers

This is where I started:

```
    CASE WHEN
    (CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(B.[Online Class Completion Date],2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(B.[Online Class Completion Date],4,2)+'/'+RIGHT(B.[Online Class Completion Date],4),103) IS NULL
    THEN NULL
    ELSE DATEDIFF(ww,A.[Trust Start Date],CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(B.[Online Class Completion Date],2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(B.[Online Class Completion Date],4,2)+'/'+RIGHT(B.[Online Class Completion Date],4),103))
    END)
<=6
THEN 'Pass'
WHEN 
    (CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(B.[Online Class Completion Date],2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(B.[Online Class Completion Date],4,2)+'/'+RIGHT(B.[Online Class Completion Date],4),103) IS NULL
    THEN NULL
    ELSE DATEDIFF(ww,A.[Trust Start Date],CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(B.[Online Class Completion Date],2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(B.[Online Class Completion Date],4,2)+'/'+RIGHT(B.[Online Class Completion Date],4),103))
    END) 
>6
THEN 'Fail'
WHEN DATEDIFF(WEEK,A.[Trust Start Date],MAX(B.[Month])) <=6
THEN 'NotApp'
ELSE 'Never'
END AS [Status]
```

Any help greatly appreciated!!

Comment: why all these `CONVERT` to handle date values? are you storing date values using appropriate datatype?

Comment: The data is imported from feeder sheets.  It can't be relied on other members of staff entering dates as actual date values.  Quite often they are entered as text hence the conversion.  It would be quite a big task trying to ensure that all dates were actually date values

Comment: please be aware that you are only delaying that big task: if you don't perform data cleanup & validation at import then you **will be bitten** in the future and will have to complete that very same task under pressure (do you know murphy? he do likes data import tasks! ^^). if it is a one time import the take your time and perform all needed checks; if it is a scheduled/daily/whatever import then reject bad data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off: 
`CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(B.[Online Class Completion Date],2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(B.[Online Class Completion Date],4,2)+'/'+RIGHT(B.[Online Class Completion Date],4),103) IS NULL` Will never be TRUE since it will contain '//' at the very minimum. Just test that field is NULL, no reason to convert.

Furthermore, because a CASE statement exits after it finds a TRUE condition, you don't need to nest like you do with IIF(). Which is exactly where you headed, so that's good.

Here's a stab at it, making minor changes to your existing attempt: (Updated to add your case to Date from Char for that awful string date field)

```
CASE 
    WHEN 
        CASE 
            WHEN B.[Online Class Completion Date] THEN NULL 
            ELSE datediff(ww,A.[Trust Start Date],CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(B.[Online Class Completion Date],2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(B.[Online Class Completion Date],4,2)+'/'+RIGHT(B.[Online Class Completion Date],4),103)) 
            END <= 6 THEN 'Pass'
    WHEN
        CASE 
            WHEN B.[Online Class Completion Date] THEN NULL 
            ELSE datediff(ww,A.[Trust Start Date],CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(B.[Online Class Completion Date],2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(B.[Online Class Completion Date],4,2)+'/'+RIGHT(B.[Online Class Completion Date],4),103)) 
            END > 6 THEN 'Fail'
    WHEN
        DateDiff(ww,A.[Trust Start Date],MAX(B.[Month])) <= 6 THEN "NotApp"
    ELSE
        'Never'
    END as 'Status'
```

Comment: I hadn't even thought of the /'s. Although if the field was null, it wouldnt be able to convert it anyway?  So it would still be null?

Comment: Yea.. I'm not sure what would happen if you tried to convert '//' to a DateTime.. I'm guessing it would just error. The way this is written now is it will check for NULL first, then attempt to convert. I can tell you from years of experience thought that if you are allowing unchecked date strings from users into a CHAR field.. your CONVERT(DATETIME,<datestring>,) formula is going to cause grief. Maybe you have better users than me though.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the appropriate nested case structure, but you would still need to clean up the dateDiff functionality in SQL-Server.

```
CASE WHEN B.[Online Class Completion Date] IS NULL
     THEN NULL
     ELSE CASE WHEN DateDiff( 'w', A.[Trust Start Date], B.[Online Class Completion Date] ) <= 6
               THEN 'Pass'
               ELSE CASE WHEN DateDiff( 'w', A.[Trust Start Date], B.[Online Class Completion Date] ) > 6
                         THEN 'Fail'
                         ELSE CASE WHEN DateDiff( 'w', A.[Trust Start Date], MAX(B.[Month] )) <= 6
                                   THEN 'NotApp'
                                   ELSE 'Never'
                                   END
                         END

               END
     END as Status
```

Now, that said, seeing a more complete query, and maybe having some precursory work done on the dates would further simplify this case construct and would prefer doing it after a review of full qry vs waste time re-converting all the dates in question... But hopefully a good jump for you to complete your conversion otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I went through all of the feeder sheets for this particular query and I've changed them to proper date/time fields to tidy up the code.

So this now works:

```
CASE 
WHEN 
    CASE 
        WHEN B.[Online Class Completion Date] IS NULL THEN NULL 
        ELSE datediff(ww,A.[Trust Start Date],B.[Online Class Completion Date]) 
        END <= 6 THEN 'Pass'
WHEN
    CASE 
        WHEN B.[Online Class Completion Date] IS NULL THEN NULL 
        ELSE datediff(ww,A.[Trust Start Date],B.[Online Class Completion Date]) 
        END > 6 THEN 'Fail'
WHEN
    DateDiff(ww,A.[Trust Start Date],MAX(B.[Month])) <= 6 THEN 'NotApp'
ELSE
    'Never'
END as [Status]
```

I was excluding some people partially on purpose and partially by accident.  I'm still fairly new to proper SQL....how do you query a query like you would in Access?